# How can I group Vertices for easy painting

Tags: vertices, transparency, vertex-groups

I am starting to paint my character with few basic colours, but there are multiple vertices throughout my mesh, is there a way to assign groups to specific vertices of that mesh, for when selected I can easily apply a material. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its possible!

In *Edit Mode*, select the vertices. In the *Object Data* panel create a *Vertex Group*, name it what you want and hit *Assign*.

[image: Vertex Group]

Now, in the 3D view menu, Tab back into *Paint Mode* and toggle *Face Selection Masking for Painting* [image: button]. You will notice the masked areas are now grayed and can't be painted.

[image: animation]

Comment: Hey, the "Assign" & "Remo" (+ other two buttons) are not appearing below the vertex groups as an option, any help?

Comment: Assign and Remove only show up in Edit Mode - Notice they appear when I hit TAB